# Поток и перегрузка оператора <<

Tags: c++, поток-ввода

Допустим, хочу перегрузить оператор << для объекта класса, тогда в заголовочном файле в теле класса объявляю функцию
         `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const MyVector & other);`  в файле с реализацей я ее, соответственно, определяю, но никак не могу понять, почему мы передаем поток по ссылке? почему возвращаем ссылку на поток, когда при определении возвращаем сам поток? И как это вообще, вернуть поток? Полагаю, такое непонимание у меня из-за того, что тема потоков до конца не ясна, буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь объяснит.

Answer (score 1):

1. Во первых ссылки подразумевают, что вы не копируете обьект лишный раз передавая его в функцию и возвращая его.
2. Во вторых состояние  потока должно быть отслеживаемо, поэтому мы должны иметь один объект  входного (выходного) потока, а не копировать, тем более, что, как правильно заметил `Harry`, потоки не копируются.
3. Возвращая ссылку, у нас также  появляется возможность написать:

   ```
   cout << a << b << c << d ...
   ```

Поскольку `cout << а`  является ссылкой на тот же `cout`, ну и так далее.

Comment: ну так поток это же не объект, не могу понять, что значит ссылка на поток, например

Comment: @Azam Почему, std::ostream - это тип. А как он устроен - вопрос другой.

Comment: Более того, потоки НЕ КОПИРУЮТСЯ, так что передать по значению не получится...

Comment: @Harry, конечно вы правы, я добавил в ответ _ спасибо!

Comment: @Azam, преставьте себе поток как  река, труба или   эскалатор, который переправляет какие то обьекты в определенное место (консоль, файл и т.д.). Сколько бы вы бревен или лодок не переправляли, всеравно река(труба, эскалатор) будет та же и по названии и по сущности

Comment: @ARHovsepyan стало более или менее понятно, но что значит, ссылка на поток? У этой трубы/реки есть адрес?

Comment: @Azam, конечно есть адрес, но вы лучше почитайте учебники.  Подробнее узнаете обо всем

Comment: @ARHovsepyan какой учебник, например?

Comment: @Azam , например  Бьерн Страуструп,  язык программирования С++ 1998 г. издания